# File Manager change in Wyvern mess up current entries?

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets, wyvern

I am wanting to change the file manager from EE File Manager to Assets 2 in Wyvern preferences.  Currently the site has numerous entries with images embedded within the Wyvern custom fields.

Will changing the file manager mess up anything with those images?
Any steps needed before making that switch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't make a difference, the images are all linked with the {filedir_X} paths once its saved to the DB, then are turned back into URLs when rendered in the template. I doubt you'll have any issues, but would not hurt to back up the DB first.

Comment: okay great, ill give it a go with backup of course, lol.

Comment: I switch between the native FM and Assets when testing features anyway, so yeah, you shouldn't have issues :)

Comment: Ran into small issue but maybe Assets related.  Unable to add image into wyvern field now.

Comment: No issue in changing over the fields, additional errors popped up regarding ckeditor but is unrelated to the wyvern/assets change.